# Why is my code giving an SIGSEGV run time error?

Tags: c++11, runtime-error

I am trying to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes in this code. This is coded keeping in mind that the range can be 100000 numbers wide with the highest upper limit being 1000000000. Online judge is giving an SIGSEGV runtime error. Please help.

I tried decreasing the array size to 100. It still didn't work. I already switched between local and global variables

```
int primes[100000]={0}, t, a, b ,i,j,k,l;
int main()
{
    cin>>t;
    for(i=0;i<t;++i)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        if(a!=1)
          j=a;
        else
          j=2;
        for(;j<=b;++j) // loop for number count
          for(k=j*j;k<=b;k+=j) // loop for finding composites
            primes[k-1]=1;  //marking out all non primes
              for(l=a;l<=b;++l)
              {
                if(primes[l-1]==0 && l-1!=0)
                cout<<l<<endl;
              }
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly on my system (I use Dev C++ 5.11) But it won't work with online judges.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and read much more about *undefined behavior* (such as [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow))

Comment: You should use `std::vector<long>` or at least do manually some dynamic memory allocation

Comment: If your program is supposed to print the primes between `a` and `b` then no, it's not quite working perfectly.

Comment: BTW, if you want to compete for online judges sites (which probably use Linux), better install Linux on your own laptop